# MS Access DoCmd.CopyObject to copy a table from another database into the current one

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

The syntax of DoCmd.CopyObject command in MS Access VBA is:

CopyObject(DestinationDatabase, NewName, SourceObjectType,
SourceObjectName)

How come there is no SourceDatabase parameter? ?

I have saved multiple specific copies of a table in another separate storage database, each instance identified with a number as suffix to the name. Then I am trying to be able to retract specific instances into the current database original table, as and when required, but CopyObject doesn't let you specify the source database, if different from the current one.

If CopyObject can copy a table to the other place, why can't it copy back to CurrentDb from where you put it? Just within my own setup, with two different .accdb databases

It works fine, to open a recordset from the remote table like this:
Set rsPrepared = dbsStorage.TableDefs(sTableName).OpenRecordset where
dbsStorage is a Database variable initialised using OpenDatabase(..)  with the path and name of the storage database. But I haven't been able to make a Table from the recordset. Please let me know if there is a way to use an open recordset in the FROM clause of a SQL INSERT INTO type query?

Comment: That command is to be run on current database to external target database. However, please re-think your process. *each instance identified with a number as suffix to the name* is not an optimal database design. You appear to treat MS Access as an application tool for data dumps (more akin to Excel) and not a relational database where tables relate in a normalized referential integrity. Consider tracking instances of data with date/time field in a *single* table.

Answer (score 0):

Nearly every action query in MS Access including make-table allows access to an external Access database in pure SQL with bracketed path reference. (Use with care in relational model.)

```sql
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 
INTO [C:\Path\To\External\DB.accdb].[newTable]
FROM mylocalTable
```

```sql
INSERT INTO [C:\Path\To\External\DB.accdb].[externalTable] (Col1, Col2, Col3)
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 
FROM mylocalTable
```

```sql
UPDATE [C:\Path\To\External\DB.accdb].[externalTable] tgt
INNER JOIN mylocalTable src
   ON tgt.PK = src.PK
SET tgt.Col1 = src.Col1,
    tgt.Col2 = src.Col2,
    tgt.Col3 = src.Col3
```

Comment: That is good, but can you also do it in the FROM clause? Like I want to do INSERT INTO mylocaltable selecting all fields FROM [C:\Path\To\External\DB.accdb].[externalTable]

Comment: Sure you can! Give it a try!